# Problems installing msodbcsql17 with Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, msodbcsql17

I have a dockerfile to upload some python code on Azure. It has been working for a few months, but today it suddenly stopped working.

The relevant commands in the Dockerfile are:

```
FROM python:3.9.5
:
:
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN exit
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

The error message is that appeared today is:

```
Err:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 msodbcsql17 amd64 17.7.2.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.214.230.139 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 104.214.230.139 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17' returned a non-zero code: 100
2021/06/16 20:50:56 Container failed during run: build. No retries remaining.
failed to run step ID: build: exit status 100
```

I believe this might be related to the .deb files being moved - or that some computer at Microsoft is down?

A good workaround would maybe be to download the relevant msodbcsql17 package directly, but I was unable to find this package in the normal repos?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some ongoing trouble with microsoft repos for some linux distributions (including ubuntu and debian). Not clear when this will be fixed.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6381

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6494

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be related to this post:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6381

It seems that some Ubuntu repositories are broken.
Hopefully it will be fixed soon...

Comment: Now it is working again. apparently the problem was that the Microsoft repo was down in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

I Will keep an eye on the resolve, but I have the same issue using:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y  mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```